# Как удалить тег?

Tags: php, html

Как удалить тег `<p>` если он находится в переменной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$var = 'some text <p> some text';
$var = str_replace(array('<p>', '</p>'), '', $var);
//закрывающий тег тоже
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы меня буквально спасли.....

Answer (score 1):

если нужно удалить все теги используйте `strip_tags($var)`